# How to make best and SAFE jQuery form check

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im' trying to reduce server load. Curently i use PHP form checks. Can somebody tell me best way to make SAFE javascript/jQuery form check? Any good examples?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about reducing server load, the only way you can achieve that by javascript form valiadtion is to catch the errors early and thereby reduce the number of form submissions you will end up rejecting on the server side.

There are no javascript form validators - nor will there ever be - that will satisfy the *SAFE* condition to the point that you can reduce server load by means of removing the server side checks.

Thus, having dealt with the *safe* criteria, go ahead and use any jQuery validator you fancy. To that end, asking for preferred libraries is considered out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer!